# Diagnose issues in .NET code deployed to a production environment, C# .NET

Tags: c#

I want to find out what methods or tools in general can be used diagnose issues in .NET code deployed to a production environment.

Thanks!

**Update**

The types of application on live: Web application, WCF application.

Comment: What kind of actual issues are you having.????

Comment: What code? a web app or winform? or a service? can you update the code or this is 3rd party? What kind of problems? performance? stability? unexplained exceptions?

Comment: In VS2010 Ultimate and I believe in lower versions, If you right click a method there is an option to create a test method.  However, I am not sure what kind of issues you are trying to diagnose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the type of issue I am looking at, I usually go down this list:

1. Custom logs (if any).
2. Event logs.
3. .NET, IIS and ASP.NET Performance Counters.
4. Add Soap tracing, System.Net tracing, System.Net.Sockets tracing.
5. WinDbg memory/crash dump analysis.

Answer (score 1):

If your .NET project is deployed to the production environment it's rather hard to debug it.

The one way is to have some logging tools integrated into software (e.g. [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)) and to analyse the log messages.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of product your interested in? Desktop or Web?

Anyway in any case you need log all unusual actions in any project.

For web application I recomend to use [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) whitch can be accessed remotelly and you can review all error and information records in it. As data source here can be xml, db or plain text file.

For desktop applications you still need to log errors and it would be really helphul to post errors to the server via some kind of "Report Bug" form.

Answer (score 0):

As a general idea, an administrative console implemented into the application can be used to query its internal state.

This can be as simple as a status page in a web application that queries if the database server can be pinged, or as extensive as a transparent pull-down console that supports your custom [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language). An example to the latter might be some games from which one can query or update the game's internal data (commands such as 'GET_OBJECT_PROPERTIES #objectId' or 'ADD_WEAPON_TO_PLAYER #playerNumber #weaponId', etc).

Comment: Can you elaborate on administrative console? Do you mean implement UI and logic?